# Managing logging levels for each WebService method independently

Tags: java, logging, logback

Here is a "war" deployed onto JBoss. It exposes a SOAP web service with several functions.

How may we have `func1()` to be logged with `INFO` level, while `funk2()` with a different level like `DEBUG`? The level should affect everything in the thread from function start till function end.

The logging levels are now managed "per package" via JBoss web console. A similar configuration in runtime is wanted in my case too.

Java, Spring 4, JBoss EAP 6.4.x, logback 1.1.3

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to be using a different logger level for different methods, it may be less confusing to have the methods in different classes, and then you can use the "traditional" approach of the logger for each class being set at the level you want for it.

But if you want to have multiple functions in one class log at different levels, you need to use different loggers for them. While the standard approach is one logger per class (with the logger named after the class), if you need different settings you just need multiple loggers (with different names).

Try something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final Logger func1logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("test.example.MyClass.func1");
    private static final Logger func2logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("test.example.MyClass.func2");

    public void func1() {
        func1logger.debug("func1 log");
    }

    public void func2() {
        func2logger.debug("func2 log");
    }
}
```

You should then be able to set the logging level for the two loggers independently. That is, while the standard convention is for the name of the logger to exactly be the name of the class, that's just a (useful!) convention, but you don't need to follow it exactly if your requirements are different.